# Where the update APK option in Google Play Console for Rejected app?

Tags: android

First time, I trying to release APK in beta version and it got rejected because of SMS_RECEIVE permission. So I removed from Manifest file, but there is no option to update APK. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Create another release, it will be evaluated and if approved your app will be available in the Play store.